# Is there a question recommendation mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

I have been always asking questions, I really want to answer some questions, but it seems most questions are irrelevant to my interest.

Why not design a mechanism to recommend some questions for us to answer?

Like, I have always been asking questions about networking or linux, I will be happy if Stack Exchange is going to recommend some related questions for me to answer, according to my most used tag.

Comment: This is what tags, including favourite and ignored tags are for; you look at the tag page and any questions with extra tags listed as favourites are highlighted in yellow, for example.

Comment: Stack Overflow homepage is already doing that. Just add the tags you like as favorite tags and you'll see mostly questions with those tags. What else you want exactly?

Answer (score 5):

This system is already implemented.

You go on the main page and change your favorite tags.

> [image]

And then posts tagged with your tags will show up in orange while the other ones will stay white.
Also, there is a built in algorithm that will show you mostly questions relevant to your favorite tags.

> [image]

Comment: +1 for making what I said in comment a full answer and with free hand circles! ;)

Comment: A post without freehand circles is a post without a soul.

Comment: Hmm... but it's not *really* red (rgb(192, 0, 0). Why?! ;)

Comment: @Sha Hum I'm at work.. it's snagit's default red color.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for questions to answer, you could do worse than clicking the great big "Unanswered" button at the top of the screen and then hitting [the my tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags). This'll hand you a big pile of questions in tags where you've expressed some interest - questions which don't yet have any up-voted answers.

Not only can you potentially answer some of them, you can also help out by identifying useful answers that haven't gotten any up-votes and up-voting them!

Answer (score 1):

This already exists. As far as I know you have two major options to do this. It's not an *exact* question recommendation, but it serves a similar enough purpose. You can sort by **newest**, **featured**, **frequent**, **votes**, **active** and **unanswered** to find the type of question you would like to answer.

[Frontpage](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Here you can add the tags you want to follow as "favorite" whereas you can also explicitly ignore tags. It will still show questions with different tags, but the ones you are interested in will be shown with a clear yellow background.

> [image]

[Bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+asp.net+or+asp.net-mvc+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+java+or+linq+or+design-patterns+or+android+or+unit-testing+or+architecture+or+design+or+oop+or+software-engineering?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

This is the approach I prefer. It utilizes the built-in search functionality which allows you to search for multiple tags. The advantages I see in this approach are:

- No yellow background (I'm just not a fan)
- No questions tagged that you don't explicitly search for
- Notification when a new question appears

The negative side here is that you have to keep a bookmark that holds all the search criteria. It is my experience that this isn't a big disadvantage, but it is a bit less userfriendly.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that upvoting and tagging questions are the mechanism in question. When you visit unanswered questions in a tag, you'll find the highest voted questions first.